# D3 linear gradient baseline doesnt sit on the average line. How do i put the lineargradient line on the exact spot I intended?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

The previous quesiton I posted had very messy sample code.
So I slimmed it down.

I tried to color two areas in the area graph which are

1. above the average line
   and the
2. below the average line.

Even if I calculated the percent value of the average value in the entire area,
Still it shows the gradient which seems slightly off from the average.

The code I'm focusing on is as below.

```
let v1=d3.max(valuesonly)
    let v2=d3.min(valuesonly)
    let offsetpercentage=(averagevalue/(v1-v2))*100
    
    let quad1=offsetpercentage*1/4
    let quad2=offsetpercentage*2/4
    let quad3=offsetpercentage*3/4
    let quad4=(100-offsetpercentage)*1/4
    let quad5=(100-offsetpercentage)*2/4
    let quad6=(100-offsetpercentage)*3/4

    defs = svg.append("defs");
  


var gradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
                   .attr("id", "area-gradient")
                   .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
                   .attr("x1", xscale(focusitem[0].date)).attr("y1", yscale(d3.min(valuesonly))-margin.bottom)              
                   .attr("x2", xscale(focusitem[0].date)).attr("y2", yscale(d3.max(valuesonly))-margin.top) 
                   .selectAll("stop")



    gradient.data([ 
                    {offset: '0%' , color: "rgba(245,75,94,0.5)"},  
                    {offset: `${quad1}%` , color: "rgba(245,75,94,0.4)"},
                    {offset: `${quad2}%` , color: "rgba(245,75,94,0.3)"},
                    {offset: `${offsetpercentage}%`, color:"rgba(245,75,94,0.0)"},  
                    {offset: `${quad5}%` , color: "rgba(22,119,252,0.5)"},
                    {offset: `${quad6}%` , color: "rgba(22,119,252,0.7)"},
                    {offset: "100%", color: "rgba(22,119,252,1)"}
                     ])             
                    .enter()
                    .append("stop")                         
                    .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })       
                    .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; })
```

The entire code is in the following link.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/KKzmmLN?editors=1011

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason for this!
I would like to share the reason.

```
.attr("x1", xscale(focusitem[0].date))
.attr("y1", yscale(d3.min(valuesonly))-margin.bottom)    
          
.attr("x2", xscale(focusitem[0].date))
.attr("y2", yscale(d3.max(valuesonly))-margin.top)
```

The parts above were the problems.
scale shouldn't have margin in this case.